# How can i clear the list display in the html page?

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

orders = []
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/confirm')
def confirm():
    global orders
    orders.append(request.args.get('food_name'))
    return render_template('confirm.html', orders=orders)


@app.route('/confirm')
def clear_cart():
    return render_template('confirm.html', orders=None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h1>Choose from the list: </h1>
    <form action="{{ url_for('confirm') }}">
        <h1 class="name">Burger</h1>
        <input type="text" name='food_name' class="no-display" value="Burger">
        <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart">
    </form>
    <form action="{{ url_for('confirm') }}">
        <h1 class="name">Pizza</h1>
        <input type="text" name='food_name' class="no-display" value="Pizza">
        <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart">
    </form>
    <form action="{{ url_for('confirm') }}">
        <h1 class="name">Momos</h1>
        <input type="text" name='food_name' class="no-display" value="Momos">
        <input type="submit" value="Add To Cart">
    </form>
    <a href="{{ url_for('clear_cart') }}"><input type="button" value="Clear Cart"></a>
    {% block subcontent %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

confirm.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block subcontent %}
    <h2>Your orders are</h2>
    {% if orders %}
    <ul>
    {% for food in orders %}
        <li>{{ food }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>Empty</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

styles.css

```
.no-display{
    display: none;
}
```

In the above the confirm.html file i am trying to clear content below the

### Your orders are

. Although i am passing the order parameter as None and rendering the confirm.html again but it content is not cleared rather None is showing up.

What must i do to make things work?

Error Screen [Note that None is showing up, which is not required.]

[image: error screen]

page must look like this after clear cart is clicked.
[image: required solution image]

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with the code

**1. The clear_cart() function is not being reached**

This might be due to the clear_cart function having the same url as the confirm function. You are using {{url_for}} which outputs "/confirm" which renders the confirm() instead of clear_cart(), one fix is to just change the name of the route of clear_cart

**2. None is showing up**

It is showing up due to the line

```py
request.args.get('food_name')
```

Returning None and being appended to a list

***suggestions***

- Use sessions for storing the cart (so it would be unique to the user)
- Use post instead of get (or just use ajax) since reloading the website will duplicate append the last item twice. (e.g if I reloaded yourapp.com/confirm?food_name="Mojo" I would get the Mojo again on the list which might not be desired)

Below is my fix/remedy on the application (the sessions being appended could be done better)

App.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Secret"



@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/confirm')
def confirm():
  if "orders" not in session:
    session["orders"] = []
  if request.args.get("food_name"):
    orders = session["orders"]
    orders.append(request.args.get('food_name'))
    session["orders"] = orders
    return render_template('item.html', orders=orders)


@app.route('/confirms')
def clear_cart():
  session["orders"] = []
  
  return render_template('item.html', orders = session["orders"])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```